# C# - SSIS - HttpClient does not contain a definition for 'BaseAddress' and no extension method 'BaseAddress' accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, ssis, httpclient

I have the following error with C#, in SSIS:

```
HttpClient does not contain a definition for 'BaseAddress' and no extension method 'BaseAddress' accepting a first argument of type...
```

[image: Screenshot here]

I have the namespace: [image: screenshot here]. I added the references for System.Net.Http

What can be the problem?

Comment: Try create a custom class that inherits the HttpClient.  Many of the properties are only accessible when you inherit the class.

Comment: You're not using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` -- you're using `ST_<stuff>.HttpClient`, as seen in the error message in your first screenshot. That's likely an entirely different thing -- select it and hit F12 to see where it's defined. It also doesn't define `GetAsync` by the looks of it

Comment: @canton7 yes, you are right. I using the following: https://ibb.co/cDWQryx How I can use System.Net.Http.HttpClient instead ST_<stuff>.HttpClient?

Comment: @mark It's likely that you generated that `HttpClient` class by accident. It's easy to do if you hit `ctrl+. <enter>` too quickly intending to add the right `using` statement, and instead hit "generate class". Just delete it (and the file it's in)

Comment: @canton7 Thanks. It works!